# Mouse works in front USB but not rear USB?

Tags: usb, motherboard, mouse

In my computer (a Gigabyte GA-EP45C-UD3R) my mouse does not work in the rear USB slots, but does work in the front slots. The back ports (which are connected to the motherboard) are enabled and work with other devices.

This makes no sense because both front and back are USB 2.0/1.1 ports and they are identical with regards to spec. Both the front and back ports work with other devices. It only seems to be mice that are affected.

Why would a mouse work off the header USBs, but not the rear USBs?

I've checked similar questions, but they involved USB ports of differing specs.

Comment: Do other devices work in the back port?

Comment: Are the back ports enabled?

Comment: Windows has a nasty habit of re-installing the drivers every time you swap ports with a device - check it actually did do that for that port [might need to uninstall first then let it try again]

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, the back ports work. I have a printer plugged into one and it works just fine.

Comment: @Tetsujin That is interesting. So, I moved the mouse to a back usb slot and then what happened? It reinstalled a driver? How could it do that? I got no message saying a device had been detected. It just acted like nothing was plugged in.

Comment: All I can guess is "it missed it first time, but saw it the second". The vagaries of Windows & even *why* it does that weird thing of re-installing the drivers for a different port - I cannot get my head around why that would ever be necessary; it already has the drivers, why didn't it make sure they'd work on all the ports it already knows it has?